# Join a string with an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, node.js

I can't understand why this test fails:

```
it('should concat string and arr', function(done) {
    var str = "update userprofile set firstname = 'Barbara', lastname = 'Jensen', cellphone = '5638499', email = 'me@gmail.com', "
    var arr = ['computer', 'business']
    str += "interests = " + arr
    var expected = "update userprofile set firstname = 'Barbara', lastname = 'Jensen', cellphone = '5638499', email = 'me@gmail.com', interests = ['computer', 'business']"
    should(str).equal(expected)
    done()
})
```

Test result looks like this:

[image: Join string with array unit test]

Comment: that is what happens when you call `.toString` on an array .you have to either do JSON.stringify or manual building.

Comment: `var str="xyz"; var arr = ["aaa","bbb"]; console.log(str+arr)` Debug it! It does not do what you think it does.

Comment: The string representation of an array looks more like a list, not an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
"interests = " + arr
```

the `toString` method in that array object will be invoked. Quoting the [`Array.prototype.toString` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString#Description),

> The `Array` object overrides the `toString` method of `Object`. **For `Array` objects, the `toString` method joins the array and returns one string containing each array element separated by commas**. For example, the following code creates an array and uses `toString` to convert the array to a string.
>
> ```
> var monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'];
> var myVar = monthNames.toString(); // assigns 'Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr' to myVar.
> ```

To fix your test case, you need to convert the Array manually, like this

```
str += "interests = [" + monthNames.map(function(currentString) {
    return "'" + currentString + "'";
}).join(", ") + "]";
```

Comment: However, I want it as single quoted string. How's that possible with JSON.stringify()?

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it. But I want it as a single stringed array.

Comment: after JSON.stringify(), I want it to look like this: `['computer', 'business']`

Comment: I did this to get a single quoted stringed array after JSON.stringify(), `str += "interests = " + JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/"/g, "'")` . Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

When you join an array to a string, Javascript will automatically concatenate out the values inside of the array.

For example:

```
var str = 'my string'+[ 'my', 'arr' ];
```

Will produce:

```
"my stringmy,arr"
```

You must serialise the array using `JSON.stringify` (or similar). For example:

```
var str = 'my string';
str+= JSON.stringify( [ 'my', 'arr' ]);
```

Will produce:

```
"my string["my","arr"]"
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the outside square brackets of your array are not part of your string, but you expect them to be. It would work if you had:

```
 var arr = '[computer, business]';
```

another way to achieve this, is to do that yourself:

```
var stringOfArr = "[" + arr.join(", ") + "]";
```

Comment: That's not an array. That's a string.

Comment: I edited the variable name, could you elaborate on why you give -1 though? Didn't it work?